# Why can't I use data after inserting to database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, email, send

Problem: I can't get the email value after inserting into the database.

EDITED:

Fixed:
my problem were `$to = $_POST['$email'];` gave wrong value to it. it should be `$to = $_POST['email'];`. 
Problem was because i had $ for giving value.

This is how I create my activation code:

```
$activation = sha1(uniqid(rand(), true));
```

This is how I declare my database insert query:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users (activation, email) VALUES (:activation, :email)";
```

Here I populate the parameters for my insert query:

```
$query_params = array(
  ':activation' => $activation,
  ':email' => $_POST['email']
);
```

...and here's how I add the data to my database by executing the query and send an email:

```
    try 
    { 
        // Execute the query to create the user 
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $stmt->execute($query_params);

        if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) { //If the Insert Query_params was successfull.
            echo 'even gets to  here.';


            // Send the email:
            $to = $_POST['email'];
            $subject = 'Registeerimis kinnitus';
            $from = 'From: mymail@gmail.com';
            $WEBSITE_URL = "http://mysite.com";
            $message = " Kasutaja aktiveerimiseks, palun vajutage aadressile:\n\n";
            $message .= $WEBSITE_URL . "/activate.php?email=" . urlencode($to) . "&key=".$activation;
            mail($to, $subject, $message);
        }
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex) 
    { 
        // Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage(). 
        // It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code.  
        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
    }
```

The insert to the database works.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Or do i need to read data from datebase back to use again after inserting ?

Comment: Use this anyway 
    sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));

Comment: okey tnx for suggestion

Comment: Where are `$activation` and `$email` declared, in relation to the `try..catch` block?

Comment: cant i give  values before declared ? that $activation = sha1(uniqid(rand(), true)); is declared before inserting to database because to active account u need to click that link.

These code pieces are in same file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
  $message .= $WEBSITE_URL . "/activate.php?email=" . urlencode($email) . "&key=".$activation;
```

Anyway use this `sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));`

Comment: yeah i saw that dot but my problem more is that it dosent get email where to send it. so there is mby only 1 way to do it ? do i need read email and activation code in datebase  to get these values after i inserted to database ?
example: 
Inserting to database email and after that i use same command to get email address to mail() function. it dosent pass the email to there.
Thats my problem :(

Comment: @Markus did you try my code ? Copy paste it in your code. and try

Comment: no because i know that i missed that dot before $activation;
But my problem now is that i cant get email value. got work that activate. it puts that in link also.
Now my only problem is that how i can get email value .
It insert in database well my email value but if i want to use it after that same way as i give value to database it dosent work.

Comment: w8 sec i think what i have to do mby,  give me 1 min to test out.
I guess my problem is that i dosent have email value but i should still send email to my email because to mail() function i give correct value if that pass it there.

Comment: okey i replace ' to " then
but i think it dosent fix my sending function to get email value.

Comment: Ok i got i work. my problem were ` $to = $_POST['$email']; ` gave wrong value to it it should be ` $to = $_POST['email'];`. Problem was because i had $ to read value in. Tnx for any help. – Markus 3 mins ago edit

Answer (score 0):

```
'&key='$activation;
'&key=' . $activation;
```

Missing a dot between '&key=' and $activation;

Comment: my bad but it still dosent give activation value to there.